# Blackberry FileConnection illegalStateException

Tags: java, blackberry, file-io, java-me

I am working on a Blackberry application that writes to the file system using the FileConnection interface.

I am getting a IllegalStateException when I try to call delete() on a certain file. The stack trace is as follows

```
IllegalStateException
    No detail message
    net_rim_os
     FileImpl
     remove
     0x373D
    net_rim_os-6
     ContentStoreConnection
     delete
     0x12DA
    com_companyName_blackberryClient-7
     FileUtility
     <private>
     0x14C6
```

The stack trace shows the exception occurs in remove() in FileImpl but I cannot find any information about this method anywhere (looks like it is a internal blackberry class)

The file is located in

```
file:///store/home/user/appName
```

Does anyone know why deleting a file from that directory would cause an illegalStateException?

We have only seen this problem once and it is proving hard to reproduce. The one occasion it did occur it is possible that there were other several other files being created and accessed in the same directory. Would this be a factor in the exception occurring?

The Blackberry OS version is 4.5.0.180 and the api version is 4.5.0

Comment: Are you making sure the file isn't open when you're trying to delete it?

Comment: Is the file a media file (a jpeg image)?

Comment: @Arhimed - no the file is not an jpeg image. It is just a temp file created to make sure we can access the file system

Comment: @jprofit. The FileConnection is open is that what you mean? As far as I am aware that is what needs to be done for you to manipulate a file. Now it seems as if two different threads are trying to manipluate the same file. I think that may be causing the problem.

Comment: @Greg McGowan: then I have no idea of what could happen.

Comment: @Greg McGowan I was meaning what you suggest in your comment, that it is open by another application/Thread. I've had my app throw an ISE when I had forgotten to call close() methods on some files I was using before deleting them.

Comment: @jprofit that looks like what the problem is. If you put that as an answer then I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the file you are trying to delete is not open by another Thread. I've had this problem when forgetting to properly close() a FileConnection or InputStream in the past.